# React-native StackNavigation pass props

Tags: react-native, stack-navigator

I'm building an app in react-native and I'm trying to put navigation into it. I have a button and I want to move to another page by clicking on it. 
But I got that error : undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation')

App.js :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import YTSearch from 'youtube-api-search';
import AppHeader from './components/AppHeader';
import SearchBar from './components/SearchBar';
import VideoList from './components/VideoList';
import TrackPlayerScreen from './Screens/TrackPlayerScreen';
import VideoListItems from './components/VideoListItems';

import {StackNavigator}  from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  VideoListItems: { screen: VideoListItems, navigationOptions: { header: null } },
  TrackPlayerScreen: { screen: TrackPlayerScreen,navigationOptions: { header: null } }
});

const API_KEY = 'APIKEY;


export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    videos: []
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.searchYT('');
  }

  onPressSearch = term => {
    this.searchYT(term);
  }

  searchYT = term => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    YTSearch({key: API_KEY, term }, videos => {
      console.log(videos);
      this.setState({
        loading: false,
        videos
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { loading, videos } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }}>

        <AppHeader headerText="Project Master Sound Control" />
        <SearchBar
        loading={loading}
        onPressSearch={this.onPressSearch} />
        <VideoList videos={videos} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

File where button will navigate to another page by clicking on it VideoListItems :

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-elements';
import TrackPlayerScreen from '../Screens/TrackPlayerScreen';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { WebBrowser } from 'expo';
import {StackNavigator}  from 'react-navigation';

const VideoListItems = ({ video }) => {
    const {
        cardStyle,
        imageStyle,
        contentStyle,
        titleStyle,
        channelTitleStyle,
        descriptionStyle
     } = styles;
    const {
        title,
        channelTitle,
        description,
        thumbnails: { medium: { url } }
    } = video.snippet;

    const videoId = video.id.videoId;

    return(
        <View>
             <Card title={null} containerStyle={cardStyle}>
                <Image
                    style={imageStyle}
                    source= {{ uri: url}}
                />
                <View style={contentStyle}>
                    <Text style={titleStyle}>
                        {title}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={channelTitleStyle}>
                        {channelTitle}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={descriptionStyle}>
                        {description}
                    </Text>
                    <Button
                      raised
                      title="Save And Play"
                      icon={{ name: 'play-arrow' }}
                      containerViewStyle={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                      backgroundColor="#E62117"
                      onPress={() => {
                        this.props.navigation.navigate('InformationScreen')
                      }}
                    />

                </View>
             </Card>
        </View>
    );
};
export default VideoListItems;
```

I'm having trouble of how to pass the navigation props to my VideoListItems, anyone any ideas ? Or am I missing something somewhere else ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you have declared the stack navigator but aren't actually rendering it. You could try simply replacing the VideoList component in your render function with the

`<AppNavigator/>`

and then adding the VideoList as a screen when declaring the stack navigator.

The first screen that you declare in the stack navigator will be used as default, so if you declare the VideoList first, you will have access to the navigation props from within that component allowing you to navigate to the VideoListItems.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

React functional form won't generate an object with `this`, you have to make it a `class`:

```js
class VideoListItems extends Component {
    render() {
        /// this.props.navigation.navigate should works here
    }
};
```